# Get $this javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, function

My goal is to retreive the text of an anchor tag by clicking it.  I want this to be inside a function not inline.  Example

```
function getText(){

alert($('this.a').text());

}
```

I know the above does not work b/c i have tried it.

I don't want this to be by id because i want it to work on all 'a' elements when they are clicked.  When i use:

```
function getText(){

alert($('a').text());

}
```

it returns ALL text within ALL the 'a' tags on my page. What i am trying to accomplish is simply returning only the text of the anchor tag i clicked.  I think it has something to do with using $(this) along with the 'a' tag but i can't seem to figure it out.

Again i want to be able to call this function for all a tags on my page without having to write a function for each id so that is why i want to use "this".  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just want `$(this).text()`:

```
function getText() {
    alert($(this).text());
}
```

And, of course, you should be handling your event like so:

```
$('a').click(getText);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's just the same as a separate function as it would be with in inline one:

```
$("selector_for_the_anchors_in_question").click(clickHandler);

function clickHandler() {
    alert($(this).text());
}
```

jQuery ensures that when the handler is called, `this` is set to the element on which the handler was hooked, and of course to get a jQuery wrapper for that element you use `$()` (or `jQuery()` in `noConflict` mode).

Answer (score 0):

This jQuery is enough:

```
$('a').click(function () {
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aEg6G/)

Answer (score 0):

You somehow have to bind the function to the click event.

```
function getText(){
    alert($(this).text()); // `this` is the element clicked
    return false; // prevent navigating
}

$("a").click(getText); // bind function to all <a> elements
```

It's not inlining this way, but honestly I don't see a reason for doing it like this.